# Traefik accessLog configuration

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, traefik

I am using Traefik 1.3.1, I put the configuration below in `traefik.toml` file but I can't see any access log on `stdout`.

Is it working for you guys?

```
[accessLog]
format = "common"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not available in 1.3.x.

You must wait the next release 1.4.

Answer (score 2):

We're successfully logging access logs to stdout in version 1.3.3 using

`traefik --accesslogsfile=/dev/stdout`

Comment: `--accesslogsfile` is deprecated. The new way to get it is using `[accessLog]`, but not in 1.3

Comment: I would argue that its not deprecated as long as the current version is 1.3.x. It is _being_ deprecated, but currently its still the correct way to configure traefik logging.

Comment: @Azize toml is not the right way to use in highly available traefik setup. I need CLI options in here, this is the only way in docker-compose under docker-swarm setup.